# Was the writing system used in the Empire of Japan (大日本帝国) called 真片仮名?

Tags: kanji, katakana, orthography, kana

So, today I encountered the claim on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kana)

> Shinkatakana (真片仮名, mana and katakana): mixed script including only kanji and katakana.

Wikipedia doesn't list a source for this claim.
This sounds to me like the writing system used by the 大日本帝国 (and I'm sure in many other contexts) with 漢字 and the 送り仮名 written in small 片仮名. But googling about 真片仮名 gives me no good results, or at least none at my level of Japanese ability.
So is this a term that is used? If not, is there a better name for the above-mentioned orthography?

Answer (score 3):

Edited:
Both Kotobank and Goo refer to this term, so it would seem legit. I may ask a blind question of some HS teachers in Japan to get more confirmation.

Links:
https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%9C%9F%E7%89%87%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D-536813
https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%9C%9F%E7%89%87%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D/

Additional information with example text in links:
During the Meiji Period, documents would be written in kanji with the grammar added using very small katakana characters. Every year I was required to transcribe the Imperial Rescript on Education at my job. It was written in this manner and some of the kana had special uses, like fu in the place of u, as seen in the first characters 'chin omou ni'.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_Rescript_on_Education
http://thinkweb.co.jp/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/120719.JPG

Comment: Your response doesn't really seem to answer Sam's question(s) -- though it has certainly left me curious about what your job was. Can you perhaps edit to include more relevant information?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I see I misread the original question and only provided information related to what the author already knew. But, what kind of system is this that immediately punishes this? I am now afraid to post further on this site because it warns me that I may be blocked for my bad posts. I am not allowed to comment on posts yet, and got further punished when someone moved an "answer" into a "comment". I don't see how a new user can become an accepted part of this "community".

Comment: Nanigashi, I am starting to gain understanding of the system here. Also, I now have the ability to comment instead of answering which seems better for initial clarification of the question before answering. You expressed interest in my job and I am wondering if there is an appropriate place to talk about that. It seems to be more about culture than language.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a "bad answer" at all, but I do think that in order to be a good answer it would need to address Sam's question more directly. That's why I suggested an edit, rather than down-voting. And I definitely don't think anyone is trying to punish you for anything, though I can certainly understand why it would feel that way if you are being threatened with being blocked from the site. I'm really sorry to hear about that, and whether you choose to edit this answer or not, I hope you won't be discouraged and will continue to post, as I'm sure you have a lot to contribute.

Comment: After the initial shock things have improved as privileges are given; however, it seems the commenting privilege should be first and the answering privilege later. I definitely agree with your assessment and might investigate the main point of the question later.

Comment: Did a little search in Japanese on the net and quickly found the terms in the commonly used kotobank and goo sites.

Comment: @ShinBikkuriman just saw your edits, so sorry for the late reply. If you could ask a HS teacher, I would be much obliged - I think it's kinda odd that kotobank/goo don't have an example or more details like they usually do. With just their short description we can be sure that the term is used, but not if it's a name for any mixture of kanji and katakana (though admittedly that seems unlikely), or the specific way of writing used e.g. in the images of the imperial rescript that you've provided. And メリークリスマス！